# Bradley Cooper's nose

Tags: silver-linings-playbook

Why did Bradley Cooper's character have an injury (a split at the upper bridge) on his nose during the entire film of Silver Linings Playbook?

Comment: The "scratch" or "scar", on the bridge of his nose looks real. In most movies, injuries sustained as part of the script are usually gone during the course of the movie if not much sooner. This one, while it may seem to lessen in severity, never really disappears and the movie begins with him having it. Why would he get out of the hospital after 8 months, as in the beginning, with this injury? This leads me to believe that it might be a real injury.

Comment: Got it...Thanks Christian, must've been an accident before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Cha Cha: When asked about the scar, Bradley Cooper said "I ran into a support beam, a stucco pillar, in the garage of this apartment I was renting in Venice Beach. The location of the cut meant I couldn't really have it stitched. I love my scar now."

The injury is real, thus the reason for it being on his nose through the entire movie. I believe it was left alone (Not Covered), due to it fitting the character's personality in the film.

He says the same thing in [this interview](http://metro.co.uk/2010/07/29/bradley-cooper-the-a-team-is-a-big-fat-wet-dream-for-an-actor-463537/).

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me to be a scratch which becomes a scar later in the movie. Looking at subsequent images from the movie, it appears to lessen in severity. I therefor don't think it is a scratch (or sore), just the scar after healing. (EDIT: Right click on image and display in a new tab to get the large version of the images.)

[image: Bradley Cooper later in SLP, pulled from Huffington Post website.]

[image: Another Bradley Cooper image from SLP, pulled from fanpop.com]

Comment: While I haven't seen the movie (and therefore don't dare to judge, not to say downvote, anything) I cannot see how this answers the actual question in any way.

Comment: The question does not match what was happening in the movie, which I pointed out. It answers the question, just not the way the OP was expecting.

Answer (score -4):

The scar is real...it appears in all three hangover movies as well.

Comment: While this is correct, it's much more brief than and contains less information than BB Stacker's excellent answer.